# Internet explorer and edge attempt to download a file as html

Tags: html, apache, download

I have an apache server that serves an html page with content similar to the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="meta/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8">       
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    
    <p><b><li>Welcome to download page</b></li> 
    </p>
    <p>
    <a href="file1.7z">file1.7z</a><br><br> 
    <a href="file2.7z">file2.7z</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the file1.7z or file2.7z link, chrome starts downloading it a 7z file, but internet explorer and edge attempt to download it as html file. If I select all files in the save as dialog box and change extention to 7z, the downloaded file is a valid 7z file.

I have found out about the [download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute which will probably fix this for Edge, but it looks like Internet explorer and other browsers may not even support this.

Is there any apache server configuration I can set, or anything I can add to my html page's header, to force all browsers to download this as a 7z file?

Comment: Have you tried using the download attribute to see if it will work in IE?

Comment: Also, what happens if you right click the file and ‘Save As’? Will it work that way on Edge, IE, and browsers you need it to?

Comment: Do you need to add the MIME type: application/x-7z-compressed?  I think you would need to do so here:  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf

Comment: @finiteloop adding MIME type works

Comment: nice that’s awesome

Comment: Can I add that as an answer that you will accept? :)

Comment: @finiteloop sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user13267 It sounds like you may need to add the MIME type: application/x-7z-compressed

I think you would need to do so on your server at this path:

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf